# Firestore Sub Collection Querying

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore db is structured like this

```
vendors (collection):
[
  vendor_ids(docs): [
    products(collection):[
       product_ids(docs): {product_object} (data)
     ]
  ]
]
```

I want to make query like =>

```
firestore.collection(vendors).doc('{wildcard_vendor_id}').collections("products).where(product_id == "provided_id")
```

product_id can be a document_Id as well. The data also contains product_id, so either solution would be correct.

**Note: The query written above is just for representation purposes only. The query may not be correct. However, I am looking for a solution on those lines.**

Thanks!

Comment: Firestore does not have wildcard queries.  You will have to find a way to structure your data to support the kind of queries you want, if that is possible.

Comment: If you want to query all `products` collections, you're looking for Collection Group Queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query. But those will query all collections of that name, no matter where they exist in your database.

Comment: My current solution uses an approach like vendors.forEach(vendor => { firestore.collection(vendors).doc(vendor).collection(product).forEach(snapshot=> if(snapshot.data == id){ console.log(do my work)})}